# Python : string contains NOT string in

Tags: python

I'm looking for a one-line Python expression that performs the following search :

```
targets = ['habble', 'norpouf', 'blantom']
entry = "Sorphie porre blantom nushblot"

found=False
for t in targets :
    if t in entry :
        found = True
        break


print ("found" if found else "not found")
```

So that we can write something ***like*** this :

```
print("found" if entry.contains(targets) else "not found")
```

Comment: The example at the end using `entry.contains(targets)` seems to represent an opposite problem (because of the `contains` word choice), though it seems that's not what you meant.  Anyhow, if you want to find out if `entry` contains _all_ of `targets`, you can either do `all(target in entry for target in targets)` or something like `set(targets).issubset(entry.split())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `any`:

```
targets = ['habble', 'norpouf', 'blantom']
entry = "Sorphie porre blantom nushblot"
result = 'found' if any(i in entry for i in targets) else 'not found'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better for `targets` to be a set?

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce It would be best for `targets` to be a set if we were checking for existence in `targets`, however, in this case, we are merely iterating over it.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce Please show how it would play with a set. That sounds good too.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> targets = {'habble', 'norpouf', 'blantom'}
>>> entry
'Sorphie porre blantom nushblot'
>>> targets.intersection(entry.split())
{'blantom'}
```

One problem would be punctuation though, for example:

```
>>> entry = "Sorphie porre blantom! nushblot"
>>> targets.intersection(entry.split())
set()
```

But this would still work:

```
>>> 'blantom' in "Sorphie porre blantom! nushblot"
True
```

You could argue it the other way as well and say that `in` may not be the behaviour you actually want, for example:

```
>>> entry = "Sorphie porre NOTblantom! nushblot"
>>> 'blantom' in entry
True
```

It just really depends on your particular problem but I think @Ajax1234 has the advantage here.